# Kusto query to cluster time-series data into 'sessions' and assign sessionId

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a time-series data of below format:

datatable(Element: string, Timestamp:datetime, Value:long)

For each *Element* there is a *Timestamp* and associated *Value* for the timestamp. If 2 consecuitive timestamps for a element is more then X-min apart, they are considered to be part of different sessions (The smaller timestamp being end of previous session and bigger one is starting of a new session). For each such session I want to calculate the SessionId (based on session start or a random guid), session start and session end.

Example: (Considering a timestamp with gap of 30-min from previous is considered as starting of a new session)

Input:

```
 Element           Timestamp       Value
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:15:00     10
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:30:00     10
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:45:00     10
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:15:00     10
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:30:00     10
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:45:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:15:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:30:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:45:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:15:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:30:00     10
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:45:00     10
```

Expected output:

```
 Element           Timestamp       value    SessionId           SessionStart             SessionEnd
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:15:00     10        guid-1        2022-03-25 06:15:00      2022-03-25 06:45:00
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:30:00     10        guid-1        2022-03-25 06:15:00      2022-03-25 06:45:00
Element-A   2022-03-25 06:45:00     10        guid-1        2022-03-25 06:15:00      2022-03-25 06:45:00
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:15:00     10        guid-2        2022-03-25 08:15:00      2022-03-25 08:45:00
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:30:00     10        guid-2        2022-03-25 08:15:00      2022-03-25 08:45:00
Element-A   2022-03-25 08:45:00     10        guid-2        2022-03-25 08:15:00      2022-03-25 08:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:15:00     10        guid-3        2022-03-25 07:15:00      2022-03-25 07:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:30:00     10        guid-3        2022-03-25 07:15:00      2022-03-25 07:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 07:45:00     10        guid-3        2022-03-25 07:15:00      2022-03-25 07:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:15:00     10        guid-4        2022-03-25 09:15:00      2022-03-25 09:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:30:00     10        guid-4        2022-03-25 09:15:00      2022-03-25 09:45:00
Element-B   2022-03-25 09:45:00     10        guid-4        2022-03-25 09:15:00      2022-03-25 09:45:00
```

The data volume is high. Please suggest with perf-efficient queries to achieve this.

Comment: "The data volume is high" - how high and if it is indeed high, what's the point of returning all rows? what is your actual endgame here?

Comment: The end goal here is to understand the session pattern for each element. How long typically the sessions are for an element and how many sessions we see in a day/week for a given element.

Comment: The data is really high with total if 50 billion rows (:() and around 0.2 million elements. Its okay to not have the Value and Timestamp column in each row and just have (Element, SessionId, SessionStart, SessionEnd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the OP comments, adding a solution with only the summarization part.
Please note that -

1. the combination of `Element` & `SessionIndex` is unique and can be used interchangeably with `SessionId` (based on `new_guid()`)
2. Since this solution is based on summarization, additional info can easily be collected per session, such as number of events per session, min/max/avg value per session, number of events with value higher than x (based on `count_if`) etc.

---

```
datatable (Element:string, Timestamp:datetime, Value:int)
[
     "Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:45:00" ,10
]
| partition hint.strategy=shuffle by Element
(
    order by Timestamp asc
    | extend SessionIndex = row_cumsum(iff(Timestamp - prev(Timestamp) > 30m, 1, 0))
    | summarize SessionStart = min(Timestamp), SessionEnd = max(Timestamp) by SessionIndex
    | extend Element, SessionId = new_guid()
    | project-reorder Element
)
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WSUWvCMBSF3wv9DxefWkhHrHPTgoMNfPDZsZcxJNpbzTBpSdKpwx%20/K9XaiZM1ecq95558CScVjvZ8jRCM16hQu8Q6I/WSwatUaJ1QRZIKh45ODN7EusREahf63rvvwWF1joPRcwdYJ%20ZxHPFeFPeBPyTdfsI5lbu8ErNb4h5vIb7/v/OgDcagDcbgBsbLpfjxBsYV8d8YV8QtMIZtMIZtMIa/MD58bw%20FME46mWtYUWjuKFoUpeVuZFdlllHo5js42vleUF2QmxTNoVHnD4RdVL094NahTmGK1pLrRKe4hRGYfDNblMqWKpBZFpwnIygMfp0LITxBjysGXQY8DE%20uNKiEkd94Mp46AidjJXVjmJ3aY0Kgptg2nQm5iXVBfHxmbTE5OGjczJalTIOapDD5Jy5cZLD6h/p3wh9IZs0hqgMAAA==)

| Element | SessionIndex | SessionStart | SessionEnd | SessionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Element-A | 0 | 2022-03-25T06:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T06:45:00Z | 5d43e356-9aae-40cb-9e2e-bd2741cc9934 |
| Element-B | 0 | 2022-03-25T07:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T07:45:00Z | df83db35-c292-4bee-a14e-0ebc2b7ef6b5 |
| Element-A | 1 | 2022-03-25T08:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T08:45:00Z | 40dbaa02-b110-4e99-8696-2505a2995553 |
| Element-B | 1 | 2022-03-25T09:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T09:45:00Z | 59d6fdeb-a596-4fab-97e5-d9057519c6c0 |

---

You can start with this.
The demographics of your data (number of records, number of elements, number of sessions per element) will determine how optimized this solution is for your specific needs.

```
datatable (Element:string, Timestamp:datetime, Value:int)
[
     "Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 06:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-A" ,"2022-03-25 08:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 07:45:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:15:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:30:00" ,10
    ,"Element-B" ,"2022-03-25 09:45:00" ,10
]
| partition hint.strategy=shuffle by Element
(
    order by Timestamp asc
    | extend SessionIndex = row_cumsum(iff(Timestamp - prev(Timestamp) > 30m, 1, 0))
    | summarize min(Timestamp), max(Timestamp), make_list(Timestamp), make_list(Value) by SessionIndex
    | extend SessionId = new_guid()
    | mv-apply Timestamp = list_Timestamp to typeof(datetime), Value = list_Value to typeof(int) on (project Timestamp, Value)
    | project Element, Timestamp, Value, SessionStart = min_Timestamp, SessionEnd = max_Timestamp, SessionId, SessionIndex
)
```

| Element | Timestamp | Value | SessionStart | SessionEnd | SessionId | SessionIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T06:15:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T06:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T06:45:00Z | 1ac146b1-24fa-427e-b2b3-663d83297d4c | 0 |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T06:30:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T06:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T06:45:00Z | 1ac146b1-24fa-427e-b2b3-663d83297d4c | 0 |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T06:45:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T06:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T06:45:00Z | 1ac146b1-24fa-427e-b2b3-663d83297d4c | 0 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T07:15:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T07:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T07:45:00Z | cbef109a-73bc-4067-9e7f-ebada6aa444e | 0 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T07:30:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T07:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T07:45:00Z | cbef109a-73bc-4067-9e7f-ebada6aa444e | 0 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T07:45:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T07:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T07:45:00Z | cbef109a-73bc-4067-9e7f-ebada6aa444e | 0 |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T08:15:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T08:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T08:45:00Z | c53fba2e-b82e-418c-9380-1e732be8fcb5 | 1 |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T08:30:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T08:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T08:45:00Z | c53fba2e-b82e-418c-9380-1e732be8fcb5 | 1 |
| Element-A | 2022-03-25T08:45:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T08:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T08:45:00Z | c53fba2e-b82e-418c-9380-1e732be8fcb5 | 1 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T09:15:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T09:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T09:45:00Z | 4ab89211-4378-45d3-8ac7-a570942e2807 | 1 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T09:30:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T09:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T09:45:00Z | 4ab89211-4378-45d3-8ac7-a570942e2807 | 1 |
| Element-B | 2022-03-25T09:45:00Z | 10 | 2022-03-25T09:15:00Z | 2022-03-25T09:45:00Z | 4ab89211-4378-45d3-8ac7-a570942e2807 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WTTW%20DMAyG75X4D1ZPIIUppftokTppk3roudMu04TSxrTZSEAQ%20jH1xy8MKKxrqwGn2K/tJ47NmTb/IkKwpxFKVNrPdCrUisCLkJhpJhOfM43anAi8sihHXyjtWL03qwfF168C3ac%20kL5HPc%20lQ9e7A3rvD%2058So15QEsxuSYe0g7i2/9nHnXBGHXBGF3BeD4VP1zBOCO%20jHFG3AFj3AVj3AVj/Avj3eodIGGpFlrECtZmaG7MaJlRWu0n2ToPQzN0iz1U6ayeXRaIU45p4TjOH7BsWfoOgDuNisMcs8xknSmOO5hAGm%20DZS6zXNoiDO0m0oUkxU1jcOARhlQSGBCgjlNnNYGSpeILQQrVUhOQbHdy/sQgEpm%20YP1ZEKfAbyNeoOcGXeE2WOWC20cYuXFZkkTtBkygSB40Bh2D3icYh3a9m061nLW2PDS6YmfBvIOdpPEHLnWTvQo81q8F1cOQP0pSX2CuzfOagqZpQUtUeaequJ9p4BnfjJOTBjnf88mtw4oEAAA=)

Comment: Please see update and share if it worked for you. Thanks

Comment: The output works as expected while due to the data volume it times out mid way when tried on the actual data. (Scale mentioned above in the comments)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-execution-timeout and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/request-properties#clientrequestproperties-options (`servertimeout ` / `norequesttimeout`)